# How do i use PSGSUITE PS module to add google groups?

Tags: arrays, powershell, object

Ok so I work for a small business, and they use a google spread sheet as the `"Phone list"`
for finding and contacting employees. I installed the `PSGSUITE` powershell module and it seems to work very well, but im new to powershell and coding in general. The filter sheet i made along with the phone list places the employees in there respective groups. Example then The code.

```
"phone list" 
Name    #   Company code    Ext.    Department  Job Title   Email
Hayden  111-222-333 JOP     IT  Technician  example@example.com
```

"filter 2sheet"

```
JOP SPD
hayden@.com lisa@.com
john@.com   arron@.com
david@.com  mike@.com
```

I want to add these emails to there respective google groups

```
## NOVA BEAZ ##
## add groups in google based on company title 
###
####
# Import Modules
Import-Module PSGSuite
# Create Array of Groups
$Title = (Import-GSSheet -SpreadsheetId "1NtCT5ruoL4Kf4-ec55xe-L8esXcSY8orfd-zOFK4q4k" -SheetName "Filter" -Headers "None"  -Range "A1:1")
$Title = $Title | % { $_ }
$Groups = (Get-GSgroup -Fields "Name" )
    if($Title = $Groups)
        #{add that users email to the group}
    #else 
        {echo "there is now group that matches that"}
```

The main issue is I really just dont know how to correctly run through the arrays and select all the emails in that row to add to the google groups, I think I need a array or object list form of storing my emails, I want this to be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Excerpts from my [blog post](https://powershell.anovelidea.org/powershell/using-psgsuite-module/) on how to use the PSGusite module.

Please check if the following answers your question. If not, let me know.

## User Process

To begin, we need to import the module and then use the command `Get-GSDriveFileList` to find the Google Sheet where our data is stored.

Next, we use the command `Import-GSSheet` to import our user and group data.

### Get Data from GSheet

```
# Import module
Import-Module -Name PSGSuite

# Discover spreadsheet Id in drive file list
$Spreadsheet = Get-GSDriveFileList -Filter "name = 'UserManagement'"

# Get data from each sheet from Google spreadsheet
$UserData = Import-GSSheet -SpreadsheetId $Spreadsheet.Id -SheetName 'Users'
$GroupData = Import-GSSheet -SpreadsheetId $Spreadsheet.Id -SheetName 'Groups'
```

### Create Organization Units

We use `Get-GSOrganizationalUnit` to determine if the OU exists. And then we use `New-GSOrganizationalUnit` to create it if it does not.

```
foreach ($Group in $GroupData) {
    $SplitPath = $Group.OrgUnitPath -Split '/'
    $ParentPath = $SplitPath[0..($SplitPath.Count -2)] -join '/'
    $OUPath = $SplitPath[-1]

    $OrgUnit = Get-GSOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase $Group.OrgUnitPath -SearchScope Base -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($OrgUnit) {
        "Org Unit {0} exists at {1}" -f $OrgUnit.OrgUnitPath,$OrgUnit.ParentOrgUnitPath
    } else {
        "Org Unit {0} does not exist; attempting to create in {1}" -f $Group.OrgUnitPath,$ParentPath
        try {
            $GSOrgUnit = New-GSOrganizationalUnit -Name $OUPath.ToLower() -ParentOrgUnitPath $ParentPath -Description $Group.Description
            "Created {0} : {1}" -f $GSOrgUnit.OrgUnitPath,$GSOrgUnit.Description
        }
        catch {
            "Unable to create {0}" -f $Group.OrgUnitPath
        }
    }
}
```

### Create Groups

Using the command `Get-GSGroup`, we check if the group exists. If the group does not already exist, use `New-GSGroup` to create the group from the spreadsheet.

```
foreach ($Group in $GroupData) {
    $GSGroup = Get-GSGroup -Group $Group.Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($GSGroup) {
        "Group {0} exists" -f $Group.Name
    } else {
        "Group {0} does not exist; attempting to create" -f $Group.Name
        try {
            $NewGSGroup = New-GSGroup -Name $Group.Name -Email $Group.Email -Description $Group.Description
            "Created {0} : {1}" -f $NewGSGroup.Name,$NewGSGroup.Description
        }
        catch {
            "Unable to create {0}" -f $Group.Name
        }
    }
}
```

### Create Users

Create the users listed in the spreadsheet.

1. First, determine the department based on the user type.
2. Using the department, set the variable for the org unit path.
3. Create the required hashtable for CustomSchemas to add the EmployeeType to the user.
4. Generate a random secure password.
5. Using the command `New-GSUser`, create the new user.
6. If the user is successfully created, use the command `New-GSUserAlias` for best effort to create an email alias based on the user’s full name.

```
foreach ($User in $UserData) {
    $Domain = $User.Email.Split('@')[1]
    switch ($User.UserType) {
        'Faculty' { $Department = 'Academics'}
        'Staff'   { $Department = 'Business' }
    }

    # Set OU path
    $OrgUnitPath = $GroupData.Where({$_.Name -eq $Department}).OrgUnitPath

    # Set employee type custom schema
    $CustomSchemas = @{
        CustomUniversity = @{
            EmployeeType = $User.UserType
        }
    }

    # Set a random secure string
    $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String (Get-RandomPassword) -AsPlainText -Force

    $NewGSUserParams = @{
        PrimaryEmail = $User.Email
        FullName = $User.FullName
        GivenName = $User.GivenName
        FamilyName = $User.FamilyName
        OrgUnitPath = $OrgUnitPath
        CustomSchemas = $CustomSchemas
        Password = $Password
    }
    $NewUser = New-GSUser @NewGSUserParams -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($NewUser) {
        'Created user {0} with primary email {1}' -f $User.FullName,$User.Email
    } else {
        'Failed to create user {0}' -f $User.Email
    }

    New-GSUserAlias -User $NewUser.PrimaryEmail -Alias ( $NewUser.Name.FullName.Replace(' ',''),$Domain -join '@') -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
}
```

> The Get-RandomPassword function is a mock-up. You would need to provide your own password method.
>
> You can omit CustomSchemas from the hashtable. The blog post shows how to manually create new attributes, if you are interested.

### Assign Users to Groups

Next, we use `Get-GSUserList` to get a list of all users in the parent OU, and then add the user to the group with `Add-GSGroupMember`.

```
$UserToGroupList = Get-GSUserList -SearchBase '/test' -SearchScope Subtree
foreach ($User in $UserToGroupList) {
    switch -regex ($User.OrgUnitPath) {
        'academics' { $GroupName = 'Academics'}
        'business' { $GroupName = 'Business'}
    }
    try {
        Add-GSGroupMember -Identity $GroupName -Member $User.User -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
        'Added {0} to group {1}' -f $User.User,$GroupName
    }
    catch {
        'Failed to add {0} to group {1}' -f $User.User,$GroupName
    }
}
```

> Note: I manually created a **/test** organizational unit and blocked automatic assignment of a license since I’m using my personal G Suite account. I don’t want any surprises at the end of the month.

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.

Comment: @AustenHolland Understood. I'll update it later this evening.